# Added property don't get encoded with JSON

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I am trying to get all `course` from the database and then add `course_has_users` if it exist.

The code works until I try to JSON encode it. Then I lose `course_has_users` when my angular front-end receives it.

```
Course.findAll({include: [
    {model:Course_has_material},
    {model:Course_has_competence},
    {model:Organization},
    {model:Module_type},
    {model:Category},
    {model:User, as:'mentor'}
    ],
    where: {organization_id: user.organization_id}
}).then(function (courses) {
    async.each(courses, function (course, callback) {
        Course_has_user.findAll({
            where: {user_id: user.user_id, course_id:course.id}
        }, {}).then(function (course_has_user) {
            course.course_has_users = course_has_user;
            callback();
        })
    }, function (err) {
        onSuccess(courses);
    });
});
```

Route

```
.get(function (req, res) {
    var course = Course.build();
    course.retrieveAll(req.user, function (courses) {
        if (courses) {
            res.json(courses);
        } else {
            res.status(401).send("Courses not found");
        }
    }, function (error) {
        res.send("Courses not found");
    });
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with Sequelize and fixed the issue by changing it's toJSON method and using `async.map`

Haven't tested with `async.each` but should work without map

```
instanceMethods: {
    toJSON: function () {
        var json = this.values;
        json.course_has_users = this.course_has_users;
        return json;
    },
};
```

Retrieve method

```
retrieveMyCourses: function (user, onSuccess, onError) {
    Course.findAll({include: [
        {model:Course_has_material},
        {model:Course_has_competence},
        {model:Organization},
        {model:Module_type},
        {model:Category},
        {model:User, as:'mentor'}
    ],
        where: {organization_id: user.organization_id}
    }).
        then(function (courses) {
            async.map(courses, function (course, callback) {
                Course_has_user.findAll({
                    where: {user_id: user.user_id, course_id:course.id}
                }, {}).then(function (course_has_user) {
                    course.course_has_users = course_has_user;
                    callback(null, course);
                })
            }, function (err, _courses) {
                var test = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(_courses));
                onSuccess(_courses);
            });
        });
},
```

Route

```
router.route('/api/myCourses')
    // Get all courses
    .get(function (req, res) {
        var course = Course.build();
        course.retrieveMyCourses(req.user, function (courses) {
            if (courses) {
                res.json(courses);
            } else {
                res.status(401).send("Courses not found");
            }
        }, function (error) {
            res.send("Courses not found");
        });
    });
```

Sequelize issue:
https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/549

Answer (score 1):

async.each will just iterate through it.
Use [async.map](https://github.com/caolan/async#map) and return course after setting course has users on it. 
It should just work then. ;)

```
Course.findAll({include: [
    {model:Course_has_material},
    {model:Course_has_competence},
    {model:Organization},
    {model:Module_type},
    {model:Category},
    {model:User, as:'mentor'}
    ],
    where: {organization_id: user.organization_id}
}).then(function (courses) {
    async.map(courses, function (course, callback) {
        Course_has_user.findAll({
            where: {user_id: user.user_id, course_id:course.id}
        }, {}).then(function (course_has_user) {
            course.course_has_users = course_has_user;
            callback(null, course);
        })
    }, function (err, _courses) {
        // Note that we use the results passed back by async here! 
        onSuccess(_courses);
    });
});
```

So you could also do, to simplify things a bit

```
Course.findAll({include: [
    {model:Course_has_material},
    {model:Course_has_competence},
    {model:Organization},
    {model:Module_type},
    {model:Category},
    {model:User, as:'mentor'}
    ],
    where: {organization_id: user.organization_id}
})
.map(function (course) {
      return Course_has_user.findAll({
          where: {user_id: user.user_id, course_id:course.id}
      }, {})
      .then(function (course_has_user) {
        course.course_has_users = course_has_user;
        return course;
      })
    })
    .then(onSuccess);
});
```

Comment: Tried it, but still gets the same result

Comment: Well, I'm not sure what yout onSuiccess does but I assume it send back the response, right? Can you log the courses object received back in
``` javascript
 function (err, _courses) {
        // Note that we use the results passed back by async here! 
        onSuccess(_courses);
    }
```

Comment: Also I'm not sure what kind of promise library you're using but you should be just able to do:

Comment: category: Object 
course_has_competences: Array[0] 
course_has_materials: Array[0] 
date: "2015-05-07T22:00:00.000Z" 
mentor: Object 
min_assignment: 10 
module_type: Object 
name: "test" 
organization: Object

Comment: I don't see the course_has_users thing here, so It's just not there :) If you use q or bluebird you can just directly map the result of the first call, so you don't need to complicate stuff with async.map see my second version.

Comment: Hm, I just checked, Q doesn't really support chaining into map, so you still have to do the first version, which sucks. Which promise lib you're using?

Comment: Sequelize, found similar issue: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sequelize/lddeQTiaz1c